# How to create a custom Authenticated API request using xAgent?

Tags: java, postman, xpages, basic-authentication

I am creating a simple API database using an xAgent,  Another application is requesting data by sending in a query in the request headers and I process the header and send back the requested data, so far so good.

I now need to add some sort of authentication to this request. but without using Domino authentication. if I use postman and send in a username and password as "basic authentication" that is not correct Domino sends back the following:

**nHTTP: user [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] authentication failure using internet password**

So if I send in username and password in a Basic Authentication request, Domino will try to login the user to Domino. However I do not want to do that.

I want to provide my own username and password that the request must match to get the data. (So if correct username/password is sent in I will send back the data anonymously to the user)

I am guessing that using Authenticated requests feature will somehow make it safer.

Can I set Domino to ignore the authenticated request for my application so that I can handle it in code?
or should I just let the external application send in username and password in the request header as base64?

advice needed

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Just use another header (it is YOUR Api), i.e. X-Auth and handle it by yourself.

But keep in mind that this lowers the security if you make a mistake...